# seleção multimensional

Tags: php, sql, select

vai parecer besta a pergunta mas nao consigo fazer.
tenho uma lista de cidades onde cada cidade tem um polo administrativo entao tem varias cidades que sao administradas pelo mesmo polo como faço essa seleção apareça em um  bem como depois que selecionar escolher todas as cidades daquele polo

```
cod_cidade  nome_cidade         cod_polo    nome_polo
033 AGUDOS DO SUL                007    ARAUCARIA
034 ALMIRANTE TAMANDARE          007    ARAUCARIA
035 ALTONIA                      007    ARAUCARIA
037 ALTO PIQUIRI                 260    SAO MATEUS DO SUL
043 ARAPONGAS                    260    SAO MATEUS DO SUL
045 ARARUNA                      260    SAO MATEUS DO SUL
```

o que eu preciso que apareça no

```
<select name='locais'>
<option value='T'>TODOS LOCAIS</option>
<option value='007'>POLO ARAUCARIA</option>
<option value='033'>--AGUDOS DO SUL</option>
<option value='034'>--ALMIRANTE TAMANDARE</option>
<option value='035'>--ALTONIA</option>
<option value='260'>POLO SAO MATEUS</option>
<option value='037'>--ALTO PIQUIRI</option>
<option value='043'>--ARAPONGAS</option>
<option value='045'>--ARARUNA</option></select>
```

eu queria saber como faço esse select no MYSQL
uma query tanto o da exibição do select, e quando selecionar por exemplo polo araucaria seleciona todos do polo.

fiz uma query mas ainda nao consegui implementar

```
SELECT `cod_cidade` , `nome_cidade`,`cod_polo`,`nome_polo`
FROM cidades AS T
WHERE cod_polo
IN (
SELECT `cod_polo`
FROM cidades AS T2
WHERE T.`cod_cidade` =035
)
```

retornou  corretamente a cidade e o plo a que ela pertence.

Comment: pensei em dois casos um com dois selects, um vai listar somente os polos, e outro vas buscar as cidades com base na primeira seleção, mas o que eu gostaria mesmo é tudo num select só. complexo né.

Comment: fiz isso que parece um caminho    SELECT `cod_cidade` , `nome_cidade`,`cod_polo`,`nome_polo`
FROM cidades AS T
WHERE cod_polo
IN (

SELECT `cod_polo`
FROM cidades AS T2
WHERE T.`cod_cidade` =043
)

Answer (score 0):

consegui fazendo assim uma array dentro de outra array;

```
$query_tip = mysql_query("SELECT `cod_polo` , `nome_polo`
FROM cidades 
WHERE cod_polo");
echo"<select size=1  name='locais'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_tip)){
        
    $queryy = mysql_query("SELECT `cod_cidade` , `nome_cidade` 
    FROM cidades AS T   WHERE cod_polo
    IN ( SELECT `cod_polo` FROM cidades AS T2 WHERE T.`cod_polo` =$row[0])");

echo "<option value=$row[0] >$row[0] - $row[1]</option>";
    while($roww = mysql_fetch_array($queryy)){
                     echo "<option value=$roww[0] > - $roww[0] - $roww[1]</option>";
                        }
                        
        }
echo "</select>";
    ?>
```